# Get script path in Dart (analog __DIR__ constant in PHP)

Tags: dart

How I can get path of the current script (not executable) in Dart?

For example. In PHP we have `__DIR__` constant, that reffer to script directory. If we have two scripts: `./run.php` and `./lib/test.php`; and in `./run.php` we just include `./lib/test.php`. Code in `./lib/test.php` output `__DIR__`. if we run `./run.php` then we get in output `/path/to/lib/test.php`.

In Dart we can get directory of the **current run** script, but how I can get directory of the **current** script?

I need in this, because I'm try to get `json`-file (that placed in library) from the library.

[image]

How I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said that when you run `test.dart`, the current directory is `/path/to/lib/tests`. So you should be able to use a relative path to open `rules.json`. The path is `../rules/rules.json` (or of course, `..\rules\rules.json` on Windows, you can get the separator from [`Platform.pathSeparator`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.Platform#id_pathSeparator)).

Alternately, apparently you can get a [`Uri`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Uri) for the current script (if supported by the platform) from [`Platform.script`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.Platform#id_script).

Comment: @t-j-crowder, thank you very much. I tried using relative paths, but made a mistake (instead of `..` wrote `.`) And could not find it. Your answer has opened my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to reference a file in the `lib` directory you use a package-relative path.

```dart
packages/my_package/lib/rules/rules.json
```

When the file from where you want to reference to another file is not in one of the top-level directories like `web`, `example`, `bin`, `test`, ... you have to navigate to the top before going down through the packages directory.
This way works within every file to every target file inside the `lib` directory of the current app package or any package you have declared as dependency in `pubspec.yaml`.

```dart
  ../packages/my_package/lib/rules/rules.json
```

`pub build` gives hints when you are not navigating up enough.

#### Example

the file containing main is in `playground/bin/script/script_path/main.dart`
the `test.json` file is in `playground/lib/some_json`

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;

main() {
  Uri filePath = io.Platform.script.resolve(
      '../../../packages/playground/some_json/test.json');
  var file = new io.File.fromUri(filePath);
  var content = file.readAsString().then((c) {
    print(c);
  });
}
```

On the server you don't need to navigate up (at least currently) because each directory has a symlink to the `packages` directory, but there are plans to get rid of symlinks and `dart2dart` probably works like `dart2js` and may make it necessary to navigate up first like in browser apps.

Comment: Thank you very much! From your answer, I learned a few new moments for yourself, which will help me very much in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a flutter project and trying to load static assets eg. json, txt, images: Use rootBundle as mentioned in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json');
}
```

Also make sure you add that file in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/config.json
```